# Nonlinear integral equations and successive approximations to solution

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am trying to work this following problem in Kolmogorov's textbook:

> Consider the nonlinear integral equation 
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x) = \lambda \int_a^b K(x, y; f(y)) \ dy + \varphi(x) \; \; \; (1)
> \end{align*}
>   with continuous $K$ and $\varphi$, where $K$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition of the form
>   \begin{align*}
> |K(x,y; z_1) - K(x,y; z_2)| \leq M|z_1 - z_2|.
> \end{align*}
>   in its ``functional argument. Prove that (1) has a unique solution for all
>   \begin{align*}
> |\lambda| < \frac{1}{M(b-a)}.
> \end{align*}
>   Write the successive approximations to this solution.

Here is what I have for this. I was hoping someone could look over my solution.

> Let $T$ be a function from $C_{[a,b]} \to C_{[a,b]}$ given by 
>   $$
> T f(x) = \lambda \int_a^bK(x,y, f(y)) \ dy + \varphi(x).
> $$
>    As $T$ is a metric space under the $L^{\infty}$ norm, to show that $T$ is a contraction mapping, we must show, using this norm, that $\rho(Tf, Tg) \leq \alpha \rho(f,g)$ for some $\alpha < 1$. For $f, g \in C_{[a,b]}$, we get: 
>   \begin{align*}
> & \rho(Tf(x), Tg(x) = \max\limits_{a \leq x \leq b} |Tf(x) - Tg(x)| \\
> & = \max\limits_{a \leq x \leq b} |\lambda| \left \lvert \int_a^b (K(x,y, f(y)) - K(x,y,g(y)) \ dy\right \rvert \\
> & \leq \max\limits_{a \leq x \leq b} |\lambda| \left \lvert \int_a^b M|f - g| \ dy \right \rvert \\
> & \leq |\lambda | M \max\limits_{a \leq x \leq b} \left \lvert \int_a^b |f - g| \ dy \right \rvert \\
> & \leq |\lambda| M \max\limits_{a \leq \leq b} |f-g| \int_a^b \ dy \\
> & \leq |\lambda| M \rho(f,g) (b-a) \\
> & < \frac{1}{M(b-a)} M \rho(f,g) (b-a) \\
> & = \frac{M(b-a)}{M(b-a)} \rho(f,g) \\
> & = \rho(f,g) 
> \end{align*}
>   Since $\rho(Tf, Tg) \leq |\lambda| M (b-a) \rho(f,g)$, where $|\lambda| M(b-a) = \alpha < 1$, we have proven that $T$ is a contraction mapping and therefore has a unique fixed point, $Th = h$, which means that $T = h$, and thus $h$ is a solution to this integral solution.
>
> The successive approximations $f_0, f_1, \ldots, f_n, \ldots$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ are given by: 
>   $$
> f_n (x) = \lambda \int_a^b K(x, y, f_{n-1}(y)) \ dy + \varphi(x).
> $$

I am most confused on writing the successive approximations, so I tried to replicate as best as I could the one example in the textbook. How does the above proof look?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What they are referring to is in [Banach Fixed Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), the unique fixed point of a contraction map $T$ on a metric space $X$ can be found by considering any $x_0\in X$ and defining the sequence
$$x_{n+1} := T(x_n) = T^n(x_0)$$
This is Cauchy and has a limit hence $x^*$ which satisfies

$$T(x^{*}) := T(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} T(x_n)) = T(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} T^n(x_0)) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} T^n(x_0) = x^*$$
This allows you to keep approximating the solution to the integral equation, by taking any $C([a,b])$ function and applying the map repeatedly. The proof looks good though.

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer. If I could ask one more question: I think I understand the general case, but am trying to figure out exactly how it would apply here. So, you mentioned we could take a $C_{[a,b]}$ function, say, $f$, and apply $T$ successively. So the successive approximations would then be $Tf$, $T^2 f$, $T^3 f$, $T^4 f$, etc. Would this just amounting to consecutively multiplying the integral by itself? I'm just trying to think of what the general form would be.

Comment: Not multiplying the integral by itself no. Instead apply the map each time, so $$f_1(x) = \int_a^bK(x,y,f_0(y))dy + \phi(x)$$ and then $$f_2(x) = \int_a^bK(x,x_1,f_1(x_1))dx_1+ \phi(x) = \int_a^bK\bigg(x,x_1, \int_a^bK(x_1,x_2,f_0(x_2))dx_2 + \phi(x_1))\bigg)dx_1+\phi(x)$$ and so on. So there is no general expression, instead you need to integrate the new function at each stage.

Comment: This makes more sense, thank you. Could you explain, though, why the lower bound of the outer integral is $1$ instead of $a$?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. It should be correct now

Comment: I would also like to note, there is no notion of rate of convergence here. So if you are doing this numerically, it is likely to be very inefficient and computationally expensive.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. If I could ask just one more question: Is there a reason that $\lambda$ is not included in the expression for $f_1 (x)$? I know that $T$ has a unique fixed point, so we say that $f_1 (x)$ is a solution to the integral equation, but I suppose I'm having some trouble understanding how we can say that $f_1 (x)$ is a solution to itself (since $f(x)$ was the integral equation we started with). Perhaps the exclusion of $\lambda$ explains why this is the case.

Comment: $\lambda$ should be included there... However, I can no longer edit the comment. What you are doing is defining $f_1$ given you know $f_0$. So in general you define $f_{n+1}$ given $f_n$. The $\lambda$ is just to ensure it is a contraction map.